# How do I edit the config file for a superset installation on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, apache-superset

I have installed Apache Superset on AWS using the quick start guide (https://aws-quickstart.github.io/quickstart-apache-superset/) and it is all working fine. The only issue I have is that my dataset is very large, so some queries take more than 60 seconds to run and superset times out. I know that I should increase the time out in the **superset_config.py** file to include SUPERSET_TIMEOUT=xxx and also SQLLAB_TIMEOUT=xxx but I can't seem to find this file. Any ideas on where this could be and how to edit the file?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and will really appreciate some help here from the community.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but try passing the parameters through environment variables, and see if it will take effect. https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-apache-superset/blob/main/templates/superset-entrypoint-existing-vpc.template.yaml#L742-L783

Comment: From the issues page on github, it's recommended that you pull the AWS ECR image, extend the `superset_config.py` file, override it in the image, then upload back to ECR and replace the image in the CloudFormation file https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-apache-superset/issues/52